# How to train a classifier with an array of arrays?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I want to use a `decision tree classifier` in order to predict something.

As you can see here:

```
from sklearn import tree

sample1 = [120,1]
sample2 = [123,3]
features = [sample1,sample2]

labels = [0,1] 

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
```

I have two samples:

- **Sample one**: `[120,1]` which I labelled as `0`
- **Sample two**: `[123,3]` which I labelled as `1`

So far so good.

But now, instead of this samples, I want to train using an array, something like:

```
features = [[120,120.2][1, 1.2]]
```

and the respective label for this sample is:

```
label = [1]
```

So my code should be:

```
from sklearn import tree

features = [[120,120.2][1, 1.2]]

labels = [1] 

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
```

I'm getting the following `error`:

**TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple**

I understand that the classifier wants a list of integers, and not tuples.
And a solution may be:

```
features = [[120, 120.2, 1, 1.2]]

labels = [1]
```

But I don't want to mix up the data, since I have it separately into arrays.

Is there any way I can train my classifier with arrays of arrays of data?

Thanks

Comment: I would personally go for `features = [[120, 120.2, 1, 1.2]]` . Never seen a tuple as a feature before and I don't see anything wrong in the solution you proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use this format with your data, you need to aggregate them in one array.

The [expected shape](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit) is **(n_samples, n_features)**.

It's even more logic, because an example is described by some features and by using the expected format it describes better your data.